# Accessing a Com server from an external app made with visual studio

Tags: c++, qt, com

I'm working on an application (client) which is supposed to communicate via com technology with a server made with qt ( qaxserver).

http://s32.postimg.org/3soas4mth/image.png

In ATL projects we have to include a file that contains the declaration of the interfaces. so that we can use them in our methods,

```
#include "../SimpleCOM/SimpleCOM_i.h"
#include "../SimpleCOM/SimpleCOM_i.c"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BSTR* message;  //used to accept return value from server.
    HRESULT hr; //COM error code;
    ISimpleChatServer *chat;    //pointer to the interface

    hr = CoInitialize(0);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SimpleChatServer,NULL,CLSCT X_INPROC_SERVER,IID_ISimpleChatServer,(void**) &chat);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {   
            hr = chat -> CallMe(_T("Zhiwei"), &message);
        }
    }
}
```

How can i access the interfaces defined in qt COM servers ? 
Is there a way to generate that header file that defines those interfaces ?

Thx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx

Comment: Qt provide a tool called dumpcpp to generate \*.h and \*.cpp files from typelibs (\*.tlb). Do you have the *.tlb files?

Comment: Yes I have the tlb file. and i already tried the dumpcpp tool , but it generates nothing @Paraboloid87

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going wrong without any dumpcpp output and without the typelib.

Comment: @Hans Passant:  can you Plz  explain to me how to access a method in an object decalared in qt?

Comment: @ Paraboloid87: i'm trying to communicate with the server written in this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-activeqt-comapp-example.html,   how can i access to objects declared there .???